# How to open an existing SQLite database with Uri object?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, uri

I'm using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to select a file.

In the method `onActivityResult` I get the Uri:

```
Uri selectedfile = data.getData();
```

How can I use the Uri object `selectedfile` to open a SQLite database? This does not work:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(selectedfile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Comment: Hi, does your app have storage permissions? What errors are you receiving? "Does not work" is a bit vague.

Comment: SQLException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database; in AndroidManifest.xml I have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: What does `selectedFile.getPath()` return?

Comment: selectedFile.getPath(): /document/3597

Comment: I've managed to load the data into an `InputStream` by using a `ContentResolver`. Is it a good idea to copy the data to a temporary file and then open this file with the method `openDatabase`? If yes, can I later use the original `Uri` to update the original database after use of `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements?

Answer (score 4):

You should not try to open a SQLiteDatabase from a Uri.

SQLiteDatabase is designed to work directly with filesystem: it needs to lock and unlock the database file and manage separate write-ahead logging (-shm and -wal) files, while Uri does not necessarily reference any content in file:// schema. Instead, it can be anything, from https:// or content:// to custom app-defined schemas.

Especially since Android 7.0 Google enforces use of content:// uris for sharing files between apps (this is exactly your case). Taken from here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html:

> For apps targeting Android 7.0, the Android framework enforces the StrictMode API policy that prohibits exposing file:// URIs outside your app. If an intent containing a file URI leaves your app, the app fails with a FileUriExposedException exception.
>
> To share files between applications, you should send a content:// URI and grant a temporary access permission on the URI. The easiest way to grant this permission is by using the FileProvider class. For more information on permissions and sharing files, see Sharing Files.

Instead, you should get ContentResolver, open the uri InputStream from it and save the stream content to a local temporary file, then use SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(filePath) on it:

```java
void openDatabaseFromFileDialog() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a database"), DB_FILE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == DB_FILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri dataUri= data.getData();
        openDatabaseFromUri(dataUri);
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

void openDatabaseFromUri(Uri uri) {
    InputStream inputStream = application.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    File file = File.createTempFile("sqlite", "");

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) > 0)
        outputStream.write(buff, 0, read);
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();

    openDatabaseFromFile(file.getPath());
}

void openDatabaseFromFile(String filePath) {
    // your code here
}
```

Also, as you're getting an SQLite stream from another app (probably, third party), I strongly suggest you work with the database in a separate Thread/AsyncTask/etc.. You never know how many Petabytes you receive :)